# Correct React Native Threads bundling for release

Tags: android, react-native, apk, visual-studio-app-center

I am working on an RN project that uses `react-native-threads`. Everything works fine until I create a signed release APK. If I run through `react-native run-android` or if I create a signed debug APK, the application works as expected. However when a release APK is produced, on running the application the following error is produced:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.mav3rik.parks, PID: 32745
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'threads/index.thread.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:22)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:170)
        at com.reactlibrary.RNThreadModule.startThread(RNThreadModule.java:98)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'threads/index.thread.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.get(SimpleSettableFuture.java:66)
        at com.reactlibrary.ReactContextBuilder.build(ReactContextBuilder.java:103)
        at com.reactlibrary.JSThread.runFromContext(JSThread.java:32)
        at com.reactlibrary.RNThreadModule.startThread(RNThreadModule.java:90)
```

more of the error can be provided if needed.

Things to consider, this is a Salesforce React Native application and it also utilizes Appcenter/CodePush.

From `react-native info`

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 68.65 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
      Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9
```

From `package.json`

```
"appcenter": "^2.1.0"
"react-native-code-push": "^5.6.1"
```

I have tried a solution where I change the relative path of `jsFileSlug` in `node_modules/react-native-threads/.../RNThreadModule.java`. But this had no change to the outcome.

The way I got the error was by listening on logcat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads#building-for-release])?

Comment: Hey, yup... I read through the instructions you have linked, and the gulp bundle task performs the task mentioned in the instructions.

Comment: I seems that you're facing this [issue](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads/issues/42#issue-345452615).

Comment: @OlivierMATROT thanks for the help. It was a build script issue. The script kinda did a Project Clean before building, which removed the threads folder in assets...